# Error in Login while retrieving

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a home screen containing four edittexts.In each edittext i accepts only single digit value.I set the requestFocus() on each edittexts.Once I enter the value in forth edittext it should call the constructor, fire a query & should return me whether login is successful or not.Instead, it is giving me Message as "Login Failed"

Here is my code

```
edit4.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(edit4.getText().toString().length()==1)
        {
            ParentDBHelper helper = new ParentDBHelper(getApplicationContext(), "db_parents", null, 2);
            SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_countries", null);
            // check if the table is empty 
            if (!c.moveToNext())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data to display, please make sure you have already inserted data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
                return false;
            }
            c.moveToPrevious();
            // if the table is not empty, read the result into a string named display 
            while(c.moveToNext())
            {
                String 
                String no1=c.getColumnName(5); 
                if(no1==edit1.getText().toString()+edit2.getText().toString()+edit3.getText().toString()+edit4.getText().toString())
                {
                    flag_status_pin=1;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent dash1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashBoard.class);
                    startActivity(dash1);
                }
            }
            if(flag_status_pin==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent homes=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),home.class);
                startActivity(homes);
            }  

        }//if 

        return false;
    }});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a TextWatcher for your edittext(s) than a keylistener:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    //Test here for login
```

}

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
};
```

Then set it  as `edit4.addTextChangedListener(watcher);` You will need to change ur logic a little bit.

Comment: @swanand: onCreate() would be fine..you can postthe updated code if u face any problems

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Strings using `==`. This does not work. Use equals instead.

Moreover, you are comparing your pin code to a column name? Shouldn't you compare it to

```
c.getString(5)
```

instead?

Comment: Thanks.But it not goes in the loop where i m firing the query.Instead it always shows me "Login Failed"

Comment: i'm not sure you can come back after you have called moveToNext beyond the limits of the cursor. I would replace the if and while and moveToPrevious by a single if moveToFirst [...] else return